# Atom & eslint update : ImportDeclaration should appear when the mode is ES6 and in the module context

Tags: babeljs, atom-editor, eslint

I updated all my packages and now I use eslint 2.4.0 and babel-eslint 5.0.0.

But now, I have got an error on eslint check :

> AssertionError: ImportDeclaration should appear when the mode is ES6
>   and in the module context.

and my `.eslintrc` is :

```
{
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true,
    "modules": true
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [2, "single"],
    "strict": [2, "never"],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 2,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 2,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 2
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ]
}
```

There is an incompatibility ? Breaking change ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**:

The bug is now [fixed](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/commit/97b24668b390b398225e8ef1bc817d6a0d1a4c59). You can safely use `"eslint": "^2.4.0"`.

---

There is a [know issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5493) about that ([here too](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4344)).

I suggest you to simply use the version `2.2.x` for the moment.

Answer (score 8):

I got the "ImportDeclaration should appear when the mode is ES6 and in the module context" yesterday(29th July 2022), but finally got it fixed today.

If you installed eslint newly in your nextJS project, edit this section of your eslintrc.json file to look like this.

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 13,
    "sourceType": "module"
  }
```

The fix for me was to change my "ecmaVersion" from "latest" to 13.

Once you do this, running the eslint command might throw fresh errors, simply update your eslint rules to stop those errors.

For me, I had to change "react/prop-type": "off" to "react/prop-types": "off" - I simply added an "s" to the "react/prop-type" part.

I hope this helps

Comment: setting `ecmaVersion` to `13` has worked like a charm

Comment: I was missing `"sourceType": "module"`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use React and JSX, the following config should work:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": 2022
  }
}
```